# Java - Predicate to find Node with set value

Tags: java, data-structures, nodes, predicate

I came upon object graphs while studying. And while they seem "cool" and useful, a related problem to the material made absolutely no sense to me.

```
public class Extensions {
     /**
     * Find any node in an object graph that satisfy a given predicate and return it.
     * @param root The root node.
     * @param predicate The given condition to satisfy.
     * @param getChildren Child selector.
     * @param <T> Type of object.
     * @return Node satisfying the condition, else null.
     */
    public static <T> T findWhere(T root, Predicate<T> predicate, Function<T, Iterable<T>> getChildren) {
        
        
    }
}
```

Root, trees and Nodes I am familiar with, but the rest i have no clue.
I thought linked lists and similar data structures was THE method for Nodes. This seems very advanced as I have not come upon anything like this in 2 years of learning Java.
While a solution would be great for me to examine and understand, a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Should return a single node matching the specified value in findWhere function (i believe).

The structure of the tree looks something like this.

```
A - B - C
        |
      |   |
     CA   CB
```

Comment: You understand *graphs*? This is one of those. You call `getChildren.apply(x)` to get the nodes that are linked to `x`.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking for here.  You want to know  what should be in the `findWhere` method?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I dont see how to use these datastructures and methods to get the result.

Comment: OK, I'll have a go at answering.  The  point is that all the implementation details of whatever structure you're looking at are tied up in `predicate` and `getChildren` - so you don't have to worry about how they work; you just have to call them.

Comment: Note that your question is really two questions, and  @Dawood ibn Kareem's answer only covers one.   Searching a graph requires different data structures than searching a tree. Dawood's algorithm only works for trees.

Comment: @Gene If you've got a more complete answer, please post it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem General graph search is pretty basic stuff. Just do what you did but maintain a set of nodes that have been visited so far. Use it to avoid re-visiting nodes already seen. You can do this. I'm getting too old to write much code for free :)

Comment: Don't know why my response to @Gene has been deleted.  But my solution DOES cover the cases that Gene claims I missed, in precisely the fashion that they described.  I feel that their criticism of my solution is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the `findWhere` method is that you've got some kind of tree structure, and you're going to search through it for a node that meets a particular condition.  As soon as you find one, you can stop looking - there may be other such nodes, but you only have to return one of them.  The `predicate` parameter is a method that you can use to check whether the condition is true.  The `getChildren` parameter is a method that you can call to find all the children of whatever node you're currently looking at.

Here is an outline of how you might write the `findWhere` method.

1. Check the root node, by applying the predicate to it.  If the root node satisfies the predicate, then you're done - just return the root node.
2. Call `getChildren` to get an iterable containing the children of the root node - maybe one of those children will contain the node you're looking for.
3. Iterate through the children, calling `findWhere` recursively until you get a node that satisfies the predicate.  If you find such a node, then you can stop iterating, and just return the node that you found.
4. If you get to the end of the iterable without finding a node that satisfies the predicate, then there is no such node.  In this case, you have to return null.

The full solution might look like this.

```
public static <T> T findWhere(T root, Predicate<T> predicate, Function<T, Iterable<T>> getChildren) {

    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (predicate.test(root)) {
        return root;
    }

    for (T child : getChildren.apply(root)) {
        T result = findWhere(child, predicate, getChildren);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I'm guessing you're allowed to assume that your structure is a tree, and that there are no cycles in it.  In other words, you're not going to run across a node which is its own descendant.  If there is a possiblity that your graph contains cycles (that is, somewhere there is a node which is a descendant of itself), then you should maintain a `Set<T>` of the nodes that you have visited already, and pass it from one recursive call to the next.  This is so that you can prevent your recursion from finishing up in an endless loop, and overflowing your stack.

If this case is possible, then you will need to write something like this.

```
public static <T> T findWhere(T root, Predicate<T> predicate, Function<T, Iterable<T>> getChildren) {
    return findWhere(root, predicate, getChildren, new HashSet<T>());
}

public static <T> T findWhere(T root, Predicate<T> predicate, Function<T, Iterable<T>> getChildren, Set<T> nodesVisited) {

    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }

    boolean seeingThisNodeForTheFirstTime = nodesVisited.add(root);

    if (! seeingThisNodeForTheFirstTime) {
        return null;
    }

    if (predicate.test(root)) {
        return root;
    }

    for (T child : getChildren.apply(root)) {
        T result = findWhere(child, predicate, getChildren, nodesVisited);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return null;            
}
```

Comment: How can i store getChildren.apply(x) in a local variable? 
I'm having a bit of trouble iterating through the tree

Comment: You could either store it in an `Iterable<T>`, or you could just write your `for` loop directly against it, like `for (T child : getChildren.apply(root)) { ... }`

Comment: If u see my updated tree structure, this wont go past B.
If i set C or its children as the right answer, it cant find it. Can you see the obvious flaw? or am i doing something wrong? 
 if (predicate.test(root)) {
                return root;
            }
           for (T child : getChildren.apply(root)) { 
               findWhere(child, predicate, getChildren);
               if (predicate.test(child)) {
                   return child;
               } else {
                   return null;
               }
           }

Comment: Yeah, you need to check the result of `findWhere(child, predicate, getChildren)`.  If it's not null, just return it, because you've found the required node.  You don't need to use `predicate` a second time within your loop.

Comment: Also, your `return null;` is in the wrong place.  It needs to be outside your `for` loop, not inside, because you only want to return `null` if none of the children contain the node you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind effort! Greatly appreciated. I now have deeper understanding of how predicate, and recursive functions works! Have a nice day!